AutoFakeBold prevents proper load of font in LuaLaTeX
I have a font – SBL Hebrew – that unfortunately doesn't have a bold version, so I need to cheat by using AutoFakeBold. However, if I use this parameter when specifying the font, since a recent update I get the following error: SBL not loadable: metric data not found or bad. If I revert to the original build currently available on MikTeX.org (01/28/2024), the problem disappears. Please find my MWE below:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he,main]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Hebrew,Language=Default,AutoFakeBold=2.5]{SBL Hebrew}
\begin{document}

Should I specify AutoFakeBold in a different way?

please provide a complete example people can use to reproduce the error and do not use minimal. it is not suitable for minimal examples. you say it works with the current build available from miktex, but you don't say which build of what that is. more importantly, you don't say what you used instead to get the error.

Removing the space works for me (but don’t ask me why). As an aside: don’t set the Script (which is set by babel) and don’t set Language to Default (except you know it works because there are no features for Hebrew). If the main language is Hebrew, remove [hebrew], too, and load the language as follows: \usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}.

@cfr I was always told here to use minimal, since it loads the least extensions that can cause problems. But the issue persists with article, so it doesn't really matter. I suppose I was also quite clear: If AutoFakeBold is there, it returns an error, if it is missing, there's no error, but no bold font either.

whoever told you to use minimal is wrong. I'm not sure what you mean by 'loads the least extensions'. minimal doesn't do a lot of essential things any class used for typesetting has to do. in particular, it doesn't do the font setup the standard classes do. the name is extremely unfortunate as it isn't suitable for examples or regular documents.

you say ' If I revert to the original build currently available on MikTeX.org (01/28/2024), the problem disappears.' I understood that to mean that if you use that build you don't have the problem. so what do you use instead that does generate the problem and can you provide a compilable example which reproduces the error?

@JavierBezos Indeed, if I remove the space from the font name, the issue disappears! Is it a programming glitch in fontspec or babel? IIRC, in the ol' days if Language and Script parameters were omitted, it gave a warning, which I don't see now, so they're indeed redundant. Usually I work with multilingual documents, hence the specification of the languages, but it's not relevant either in this particular case.

@cfr Come on, leave this minimal stuff alone. Since the official release obviously there has been various updates. It seems that one of them changed the way how font names are handled.

@JavierBezos there have been several bugs/issues involving spaces ...

this is a luaotfload bug, and with the dev version it works again.

@Kazibácsi Yes, fontspec showed a warning, which was mostly useless and even misleading. Many people have been configuring the font incorrectly because of it. Currently, it’s just a more correct ‘info’.

@Kazibácsi see https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/285

Based on comments of Javier Bezos and Ulrike Fischer, the problem seems to be with luaotfload, which can be circumvented by omitting any white spaces in the name of the given font.

Load the font by filename, e.g.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[import=he,main]{hebrew}

% Available at: https://www.sbl-site.org/educational/BiblicalFonts_SBLHebrew.aspx
\defaultfontfeatures[SBL_Hbrw]{
    Scale=MatchLowercase,
    AutoFakeBold = 2.5,
    AutoFakeSlant = -0.15,
    Renderer=HarfBuzz,
    Extension=.ttf}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}
          {SBL_Hbrw} % Should load Language= and Script= automatically.


Is your answer anything different than the solution proposed by Javier in his comment?

@Kazibácsi It’s along the same lines, but not the same.

@Kazibácsi Specifically, the filename (SBL_Hbrw.ttf) is not the same as the display name with spaces removed (SBLHebrew).
